# Number of monic polynomials = $q^n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields

In the situation $q=p^k$ with $p$ prime and $k \in \mathbb{N}$ I have the following question:

Why is the number of monic polynomials of degree $n$ in $\mathbb{F}_q[X]$  $$q^n \ ?$$

Comment: How many choices are there for the coefficient of $X^r$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've never read an explanation, because it is probably considered obvious.

Monic polynomials of degree $n$ look like $x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \dots + a_1 x + a_0$. How many options are there for each of the $a_i$?

Comment: You mean it's so easy that I can say for every coefficient $a_i$ I have $q$ opportunities because $|\mathbb{F}_q|=q$ and so I have $q^n$.

Comment: Yes, that's all there is to it.

Comment: So I think this works for any finite field - nice to find the number of polynomials anyway.

Comment: Yes, and in a certain sense something similar 'works' for infinite fields: the set of polynomials of degree $< n$ (not necessarily monic, not all of the same degree) forms a vector space of dimension $n$ over the base field. (And here you just add an extra $x^n$ at the front to make it monic and always of degree $n$.)

Comment: So the $n$-dimensional basis would be $(X^0,X^1,X^2, \cdots, X^{n-1})$ in this case.